# Msn account not connecting on Empathy

Tags: empathy, connection, msn

Msn keeps "connecting" without actually doing so eventually.
isn't the:
server: messenger.hotmail.com
port: 1863?

Comment: just for 1 account ?
Wich version of empathy ?

Comment: 2.32.0  
yes doesn't work, not even for a single account.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue last night.  Check if you have telepathy-butterfly installed and remove it.

See Ubuntu Software Center and search for telepathy-butterfly then click remove

or remove it by using terminal

> sudo apt-get remove telepathy-butterfly

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to close down Empathy, delete my MSN account, and re-add it (the form changes, so you know it's done something) and then it worked.